Adapter not attached recyclerview
I am trying to make a storytelling application that lets you see other's post, taken from a dummy API, but i just can't get the recyclerview list to work, as it only ever give me error, saying the adapter is not attached. Here are the codes for MainActivity.
package com.example.makemystory.view.main

import android.animation.AnimatorSet
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.View
import android.view.WindowInsets
import android.view.WindowManager
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.makemystory.R
import com.example.makemystory.data.helper.ViewModelFactory
import com.example.makemystory.data.network.StoryResponse
import com.example.makemystory.view.welcome.WelcomeActivity
import com.example.makemystory.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel> {
        ViewModelFactory.getInstance(this)
    }
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setTitle("Make my Story")
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.rvStory.layoutManager = layoutManager
        val itemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(this, layoutManager.orientation)
        binding.rvStory.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration)

        viewModel.stories.observe(this) {storyResponse ->
            setStoryData(storyResponse)
        }

        viewModel.isLoading.observe(this) {
            showLoading(it)
        }

        viewModel.getSession().observe(this) { user ->
            if (!user.isLogin) {
                startActivity(Intent(this, WelcomeActivity::class.java))
                finish()
            } else {
                viewModel.getStories()
            }
        }

        setupView()
    }

    private fun setStoryData(storyResponse: StoryResponse) {
        val consumerStory = storyResponse.listStory
        val adapter = StoryAdapter()
        adapter.submitList(consumerStory)
        binding.rvStory.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    private fun setupView() {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
        } else {
            window.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            )
        }
        supportActionBar?.hide()
    }

    private fun showLoading(isLoading: Boolean) {
        binding.progressBar.visibility = if (isLoading) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
}

here is the ViewModel
package com.example.makemystory.view.main

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.asLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.makemystory.data.pref.UserModel
import com.example.makemystory.data.helper.UserRepository
import com.example.makemystory.data.network.ErrorResponse
import com.example.makemystory.data.network.StoryResponse
import com.google.gson.Gson
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import retrofit2.HttpException

class MainViewModel(private val repository: UserRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _stories = MutableLiveData<StoryResponse>()
    val stories: LiveData<StoryResponse> = _stories

    private val _isLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isLoading: LiveData<Boolean> = _isLoading

    fun getStories() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _isLoading.value = true
            try {
                val response = repository.getStories()
                _stories.value = response
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                val errorBody = e.response()?.errorBody()?.string()
                if (errorBody != null && errorBody.startsWith("<html>")) {
                    handleError("JSON not found, instead HTML was found.")
                } else {
                    val errorResponse = Gson().fromJson(errorBody, ErrorResponse::class.java)
                    val errorMessage = errorResponse?.message ?: "Unknown error"
                    handleError(errorMessage)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                handleError("An error occurred: ${e.message}")
            } finally {
                _isLoading.value = false
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleError(errorMessage: String) {
        _stories.value = StoryResponse(error = true, message = errorMessage)
    }

    fun getSession(): LiveData<UserModel> {
        return repository.getSession().asLiveData()
    }

    fun logout() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.logout()
        }
    }

}

and here is the Adapter
`package com.example.makemystory.view.main

import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.makemystory.data.network.ListStoryItem
import com.example.makemystory.databinding.ItemStoryBinding

class StoryAdapter : ListAdapter<ListStoryItem, StoryAdapter.MyViewHolder>(DIFF_CALLBACK) {
    class MyViewHolder (val binding: ItemStoryBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        fun bind(story: ListStoryItem) {
            binding.tvTitle.text = story.name
            binding.tvDescription.text = story.description
            Glide.with(binding.root.context)
                .load(story.photoUrl)
                .into(binding.ivItem)
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemStoryBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(binding)
    }


    companion object{
        val DIFF_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ListStoryItem>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ListStoryItem, newItem: ListStoryItem): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ListStoryItem, newItem: ListStoryItem): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }
        }
    }
}

I would appreciate any helps or insights, further need of more codes are open and i am always gonna be willing to take give more codes if the ones above are not enough!
I tried so many things, i even tried using chatgpt but nothing just seem to work, im at my wits end, what i expected to happen was, after logging in, the api is gonna get the token from my account, uses it to get datas from it, and come back bringing datas for the app to show on a recyclerview, but what actually happened was just white screen.

Create and attach your StoryAdapter inside onCreate, not in your setStoryData function. In your setStoryData function, you can just call submitList on the preexisting StoryAdapter.  This way, it will start with an empty list and animate the addition of new items when you submit the loaded data and each time the list changes. It will also get rid of the warning (not error) message you are seeing about no adapter being attached.

Your ListStoryItem class should have a property for a unique Id to represent each row, and this is what you should be comparing in areItemsTheSame().

As for why you’re not seeing anything loaded, I think you forgot to call viewModel.getStories(). Also, in your ViewModel’s coroutine, you cannot simply catch and swallow all types of Exceptions, or the coroutine will leak memory and resources if the ViewModel is destroyed while the coroutine is running. You should check if the exception is a CancellationException, and if it is, you need to rethrow it.
